# Duplicate/change attribute of multiple elements based on pre-existing, unique attribute per element

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, attr

How can I create attributes for a set of elements that already have these created (dynamically created) and dupe & change on the same respective elements? eg:

```
<div class="category" data-category-name="Pizza">Pizza</div>
<div class="category" data-category-name="Burgers">Burgers</div>
<div class="category" data-category-name="Drinks">Drinks</div>
```

These need to have another attribute added, say "data-open-category", and that needs to get the value of the "data-category-name" attribute like the following:

```
<div class="category" data-category-name="Pizza" data-open-category="Pizza">Pizza</div>
<div class="category" data-category-name="Burgers" data-open-category="Burgers">Burgers</div>
<div class="category" data-category-name="Drinks" data-open-category="Drinks">Drinks</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `.attr()` , `.data()`

```js
$("[data-category-name]").attr("data-open-category", function(_, val) {     
  // set both `.attr()` , `.data()`
  return ($(this).data().openCategory = $(this).data().categoryName)
});
$("[data-open-category]").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).data(), $(this).attr("data-open-category"))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="category" data-category-name="Pizza">Pizza</div>
<div class="category" data-category-name="Burgers">Burgers</div>
<div class="category" data-category-name="Drinks">Drinks</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each` add the Data `attr`

```
  $(".category").each(function() {
    var cat = $(this).data("category-name")

    $(this).attr("data-open-category", cat)

})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4qzf1Lm/)